# Canvas Vertical Wave

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have this canvas have made in horizontal. But what I want to achive is a vertical wave. I tried to change the values from x to y but unfortunately that didn't work.

First thing I want to make it vertically. And after I achive that I want to make a square like this. But one step at a time.

On local I made the wave vertically but the mouse movement from this function didn't work.

```
function onMouseMove(event) {
  var mouseX = event.clientX;
  var mouseY = event.clientY;
  var xPart;
  if(Math.abs(_halfStageHeight - mouseY) < _colRadius) {
    if(_allowHitBool){
        _mouseYSpeed = mouseY - _oldMouseY;
        xPart = Math.floor(mouseX/_particleDistNum);
        _particleArray[xPart].yVel = _mouseYSpeed/2;
      _allowHitBool = false;
      setTimeout(function() {
        _allowHitBool = true;
      }, 100);
    }
  }

  _oldMouseX = mouseX;
  _oldMouseY = mouseY;

}
```

This is the horizontal wave. [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6v7e1wes/)

Thank you

Comment: _"I tried to change the values from x to y but unfortunately that didn't work"_ - what about widths/heights? For example in that snippet above, you have `Math.abs(_halfStageHeight - mouseY)` - would perhaps make sense to switch out that one too (and possible other occurrences as well.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use transformations to rotate the canvas 90 degrees to vertical:

```
function init() {
  var stage = document.getElementById('stage');
 _stageWidth = stage.width = window.innerWidth;
  _stageHeight = stage.height = window.innerHeight;
  _halfStageHeight = _stageHeight/2;
  _stageContext = stage.getContext('2d');
    _stageContext.fillStyle = "#fff";
  _particleDistNum = _stageWidth/(_totalParticles-1);
  createParticles();

  // rotate the canvas 90 degrees to vertical
  _stageContext.translate(stage.width/2,stage.height/2);
  _stageContext.rotate(Math.PI/2);
  _stageContext.translate(-stage.width/2,-stage.height/2);
}
```